# Amazon s3 not deleting directory that contains large no. of files? How to delete large size folder?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The command that I'm using is -

```
aws s3 rm --recursive --debug s3://abc-elastic-snap-shot/sample-bash-rest-ex/abccom/sarthak/ --endpoint-url https://abc.xyz.com
```

The output that I see in the scree is the list of files getting deleted but when I check the directory those files have not been deleted. The command doesn't throw any error at all. When I use the same command for a directory that has less no. of files then it works. I think it has something to do with `--page-size` as the maximum value is 1000, but is there a way to efficiently delete a directory and atleast get a meaninful error for handling?

Comment: Side-question: Why are you including an `--endpoint-url`? There should be no need for this if you are using Amazon S3. You might need a `--region` parameter, but not `endpoint-url`.

Comment: I'm using my own organisation storage which is s3 compatible

Comment: In that case, it might be a problem with the implementation of the S3-compatible system. Since you aren't using Amazon S3, it's not an AWS issue.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein might be but when I used a 3rd party tool s3cmd that worked forme. Same is the problem with sync command. When I re-run the awss3 sync command it re-uploads all files again. I have passed --size-only, --timestamp options. It didn't worked but with s3cmd the sync comman works as well. I don't think I'm allowed to use 3rd party tool so stuck for now.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein The issue seems to be with the latest version of the aws command line tool i.e. 1.16. It was re-uploading files. So when I installed an older version of the tool i.e. 1.15 that is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the latest version of the aws command line tool i.e. 1.16. It was re-uploading files. So when I installed an older version of the tool i.e. 1.15 that is working fine.